# Android list view using custom adapter and view holder

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to make a custom adapter using a view holder.

```
Log.i(CardHolderConstants.LOGIN_INFO, "cardsize>0");
        myListAdapater=new MyListAdapater(this,cardList);       
        listview.setAdapter(myListAdapater);
```

Here i am calling the class mylist which extends baseadpater.
CardList contains a list of card objects retrieved from the database.

```
    static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView cardId,cardNumber,cardName;

    }

    class MyListAdapater extends BaseAdapter{
        List<Card> cardListForDisplay;
         LayoutInflater inflater ; Context context;
        public MyListAdapater(Context context,List<Card> cardListForDisplay) {
            super();
            Log.i(CardHolderConstants.LOGIN_INFO, "inside mylist");
            this.cardListForDisplay = cardListForDisplay;
            this.context=context;

        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return cardListForDisplay.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup parent) {            
            View rowView = view; 
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(rowView==null){  
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_list, parent, false);                  
                  holder.cardId=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.displayCardID);
                  holder.cardName=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.displayCardName);
                  holder.cardNumber=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.displayCardNumber);
                  rowView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
                holder=(ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }
            Log.i(CardHolderConstants.CARD_HOLDER, "inside getView class");
            for(Card card:cardListForDisplay){
                if(card!=null){
                long cardID= card.getCardId();
                String cardName=card.getCardName();
                long cardNumber=card.getCardNumber();
                if(Utils.isNumberNullOrEmpty(cardID)==false && Utils.isNumberNullOrEmpty(cardNumber)==false
                        && Utils.isStringNullOrEmpty(cardName)==false)
                 holder.cardId.setText(Long.toString(cardID));
                 holder.cardNumber.setText(Long.toString(cardNumber));
                 holder.cardName.setText(cardName);
                }
            }


            return rowView;
        }

    }
}
```

when the class is initialized the get view method is not being called.
The log in the constructor gets printed.why is my `getview` method not being called.
the list is being displayed . but the same item is being displayed. What is the correct way of iterating within the listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Should be

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return cardListForDisplay.size();
}
```

Also change to

```
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0; // can be cardListForDisplay.get(arg0)
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return arg0; // can be cardListForDisplay.indexOf(getItem(arg0))
}
```

Edit:

```
Card card = (Card) cardListForDisplay.get(position);      
long cardID= card.getCardId();
String cardName=card.getCardName();
long cardNumber=card.getCardNumber();
holder.cardId.setText(Long.toString(cardID));
holder.cardNumber.setText(Long.toString(cardNumber));
holder.cardName.setText(cardName);
```

Comment: Sorry it was correct. While pasting, the class name got joined with extends.  It would have thrown compilation error otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, its because i was not returning the size.

Comment: @Ciff there is no need for `for` loop also. see the edit

Comment: the list is being displayed . but the same item is being displayed. What is the correct way of iterating within the listview

Comment: @Ciff check the edit. it should work remove for loop

Answer (score 2):

You have to change two things,

1. Change getItem method from,

   ```
   @Override
   public Object getItem(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
   }
   ```

to

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cardListForDisplay.get(arg0);
    }
```

1. Your get View method should do the work for one view i.e. one row at a time. As this will be called for each row, so need of for loop there.

Change it to the below,

```
    if(rowView==null){  
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
              rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_list, parent, false);                  
              holder.cardId=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.displayCardID);
              holder.cardName=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.displayCardName);
              holder.cardNumber=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.displayCardNumber);
              rowView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        Log.i(CardHolderConstants.CARD_HOLDER, "inside getView class");
        Card card = getItem(position);
            if(card!=null){
            long cardID= card.getCardId();
            String cardName=card.getCardName();
            long cardNumber=card.getCardNumber();
            if(Utils.isNumberNullOrEmpty(cardID)==false && Utils.isNumberNullOrEmpty(cardNumber)==false
                    && Utils.isStringNullOrEmpty(cardName)==false)
             holder.cardId.setText(Long.toString(cardID));
             holder.cardNumber.setText(Long.toString(cardNumber));
             holder.cardName.setText(cardName);
            }    


        return rowView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change here from

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return cardListForDisplay.size();
}
```

also here

```
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}
```

Finally Change this

```
class MyListAdapaterextends BaseAdapter{
```

to

```
class MyListAdapaterextends extends BaseAdapter{
```

Comment: Sorry it was correct. While pasting, the class name got joined with extends.  It would have thrown compilation error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

override 'getCount' properly .... check 'return' value of this method

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCount()` method has the hard coded the return to 0 . So the `ListAdapter` thinks there are no items in your list/array of list objects.

Change this:

```
 @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
```

to something like:

```
return sizeOfyourList;
```