# Checkbox in Spinner adapter is automatically checked when I scroll it

Tags: android, checkbox

**What I have:** I have a spinner, foe which I have set the adapter, the adapter displayed in coed below has a `checkbox` and a `textview`

**What is happening**:: When I check the checkbox in one row and scroll below, some item in the below adapter is checked automatically. also when i scroll back up the adapter i checked also remained checked

**What I am trying to do**::
How can I preserve the proper selection of checkbox in the adapter all teh time. when i scroll up and down

---

**AdptCategories.java**

```
public class AdptCategories extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categorySpinnerData;
    Context context;
    //ArrayList<ListObject> objects;

    public AdptCategories(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _categorySpinnerData, Context _context) {
        super();
        context=_context;
        categorySpinnerData=_categorySpinnerData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categorySpinnerData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return categorySpinnerData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HashMap<String, String> mapData=categorySpinnerData.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_categories_spinner, null);
        }

        TextView txtCategoryNameId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryNameId);
        CheckBox categoryChkBxId = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryChkBxId);
        if(position==0){
            txtCategoryNameId.setText(mapData.get("name"));
            categoryChkBxId.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            txtCategoryNameId.setText(mapData.get("name"));
            txtCategoryNameId.setTag(mapData.get("id"));
            categoryChkBxId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

### {EDIT}

```
public class AdptCategories extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categorySpinnerData;
    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    //ArrayList<ListObject> objects;

    public AdptCategories(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _categorySpinnerData, Context _context) {
        super();
        context=_context;
        categorySpinnerData=_categorySpinnerData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categorySpinnerData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return categorySpinnerData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView txtCategoryNameId;
        static CheckBox categoryChkBxId;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        HashMap<String, String> mapData=categorySpinnerData.get(position);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) 
        {
            checked.add(i, false);
        }

        ViewHolderItem.categoryChkBxId.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkbox,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    checked.set(position,true);
                }
                else
                { 
                    checked.set(position,false);
                }  
            }
        });
        ViewHolderItem.categoryChkBxId.setChecked(checked.get(position));

        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_categories_spinner, null);
            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.txtCategoryNameId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryNameId);
            viewHolder.categoryChkBxId = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryChkBxId);

            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource every time
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(position==0){
            viewHolder.txtCategoryNameId.setText(mapData.get("name"));
            viewHolder.categoryChkBxId.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            viewHolder.txtCategoryNameId.setText(mapData.get("name"));
            viewHolder.txtCategoryNameId.setTag(mapData.get("id"));
            viewHolder.categoryChkBxId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: use [ViewHolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317735/android-list-view-using-custom-adapter-and-view-holder)

Comment: AdapterView reuse the views on scroll so better keep track of the checked items with the help of an Array and in getView method make the check box checked and un-checked

Comment: @Triode I'm facing with same problem. I use custom adapter to fill my listview rows. I made my listview multiple choice. When i scrolling listview my checks are disappear. How can i fix this situation ? Should i use new array for selected items ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714738/checkedtextview-disappears-when-scroll-in-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is due to the recycling of views in spinner,what you can do is declare an boolean array `private ArrayList<Boolean> checked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();`
and initialize in your adapter constructor

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) 
 {
 checked.add(i, false);
 }
```

and now your get view method use it like this:-

```
your_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkbox,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (isChecked)
             {
             checked.set(position,true);
             }
             else
             { 
             checked.set(position,false);
             }  
        }
    });
    your_checkbox.setChecked(your_data.get(position));
```

and please use viewholder, its a good practice.

Comment: What is `your_data` in your anser is it you are refering to `ArrayList<Boolean> checked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();`

Comment: its your arraylist you are passing to populate the spinner

Comment: `ViewHolderItem.categoryChkBxId.setChecked(categorySpinnerData.get(position));` ........... i get error as `The method setChecked(boolean) in the type CompoundButton is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,String>)` ........ also i was asked to make `getView` position to make final ...is it not a problem ?

Comment: sorry my bad i was in a hurry your_data is checked and yes you can make position final it won't cause any problem,you have implemented viewholder pattern it will improve efficiency and speed always while implementing an adapter use the viewholder pattern it is a good practice

Comment: Thansk, please check the edit .... i have a null pointer exception at `ViewHolderItem.categoryChkBxId.setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: declare a viewholder static class and move the checked arraylist's initialization into constructor of Baseadapter from the getview method

Comment: first inflate your view then implement the setOnCheckedChangeListener at last before the return statement