# Row item view position issue in RecyclerView android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recyclerview having radio button as recyclerview item. I have to select all other radio button as false without currently selected radio button. So I have done -

```
View.OnClickListener rbClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) v;
            if (lastCheckedRB != null && lastCheckedRB != checked_rb) {
                lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
            }

            lastCheckedRB = checked_rb;


        }
    };

    mainHolder.radioBtnTrip.setOnClickListener(rbClick);
```

Its working fine when i have 4 to 5 items. But when it has more than 5 items then always multiple radio button is selected as true because of view recycle. Given photo indicate that first item is selected but also 10th radio button is selected when I scroll.

[image: First image]

[image: 2nd Image]

How to resolve the row item position issue. I must have to select only one radio button at a time and select all other radio button of recyclerview as false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438858/checkbox-in-spinner-adapter-is-automatically-checked-when-i-scroll-it/27438944#27438944 you can solve this by this answer

Answer (score 0):

Override the method [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) to format the viewholder in many different way based on the value ( or whatever ) of the view

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

   // example
   return 0;

}
```

then, in your onBindViewHolder method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


    if( this.getItemViewType(position)==1){
        // layout #1
    }else{ 
        // layout #2
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Understand the way recyclerview or listview works

You have to store the checked status somewhere to update when the bindview is called , where you can set the checked status to true.

Listview or RecyclerView will reuse view from any index on scrolling.

Same view that you have selected before cannot be expected on the same index when your scrolling back.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to create a property in the respective model and then inside onBindViewHolder() set the radio buttons checked property according to the model